# where shall i get sun IDM?

Tags: java

I want to learn Sun IDM. From where can I download?
Please give me suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

1. https://edelivery.oracle.com/
2. English, Continue
3. enter Name etc.
4. Select a Product Pack: Sun Products
5. choose platform: Oracle Solaris on SPARC - 32 bit (really, doesn't matter which system you're actually running)
6. Select the "Sun Products Media Pack", Continue
7. Scroll down and see: Sun Identity Manager 8.1

Answer (score 0):

Sun IDM has been re-branded to [Oracle Waveset](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/waveset-101990.html), but I don't know any download location. You can *buy* the oracle identity manager (OIM) [here](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/identity-management/oracle-identity-manager/index.html).

**Reference**

- [Talking Identity](http://blog.talkingidentity.com/2010/01/expanding-on-the-oracle-sun-idm-strategy.html)